# Query Error for group by function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql Query throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348102/sql-query-throwing-error)

I am trying a query for retrieving records according to divisions and display according to months and i have to sum up the salary allowance month wise, nd also show them month wise.

Here's the query im trying :-

```
select  
    pmc.[month] as 'Month', 
    pmc.pd_name_of_project as 'Name of Project',
    tbl_div.name AS 'Name of Advisory Services Division',
    TBL_PMC_UNIT.UNIT_NAME AS 'Name of Unit',
    pmc.pd_project_type as 'Project Type',
    pmc.accepted_tender_cost as 'Accepted Tender Cost',
    pmc.work_order_date as 'Work Order Date',
    pmc.tender_period_months as 'Tender Period',
    pmc.project_completion_date as 'Project Completion Date',
    pmc.per_pmc_charges as '% Of PMC Charges',
    pmc.total_pmc_charges_scheme as 'Total PMC amount   of the Scheme',
    pmc.bill_amount_certified_upto_previous_month as 'Bill amount certified upto previous Month',     
    pmc.total_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Total PMC charges  upto previous Month',
    pmc.receipt_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Receipt of PMC Charges upto previous Month',
    pmc.balance_of_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Balance of PMC charges upto previous Month',
    pmc.bill_amount_certified_current_month as 'Bill amount certified During Current Month',
    pmc.PMC_charges_for_current_month as ' PMC charges  During Current Month',
    pmc.receipt_PMC_charges_current_month as 'Receipt of PMC Charges During Current Monthh',
    pmc.balance_of_PMC_charges_current_month as 'Balance of PMC charges During Current Month',
    SUM(pmc.salary_allowance) as 'Salary & Allowance Division'
FROM 
    TBL_PMC pmc 
        INNER JOIN TBL_DIV 
            ON TBL_DIV.ID = pmc.DIV_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_PMC_UNIT 
            ON TBL_PMC_UNIT.ID=pmc.UNIT_ID  
WHERE 
    pmc.div_id= 17 
    --and pmc.unit_id=@unit_id;
group by  
    pmc.[month]
```

Im having the following error :- 
Column 'TBL_PMC.pd_name_of_project' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. 
I dont want to use aggregate functions on all columns....just a few columns i have to sum up!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the GROUP statement you can use columns in the `SELECT` which are contained in the GROUP BY or has an aggregate function. - as the error message said.

You can try to use the `SUM...OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` clause in this case. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

So delete the Group By line and change your sum like this:

```
SUM(pmc.salary_allowance) OVER(PARTITION BY pmc.[month])
```

Comment: Partition by works fine.....but the thing is...if the month of june has 3 records in it....3 rows of data comes as expected, but the sum of salary allowance is also displayed 3 times. [ as many rows are there , as many times the same sum is displayed]. Any idea to get around this one. I just want to display the sum only once for a month

Answer (score 2):

You might not want to, but you have to. Or put the columns in the `GROUP BY` section. Like the previous answer told you

Answer (score 0):

Placing the fields in a `GROUP BY` is required.  You might be able to use the following though to query the data:

```
select  pmc1.[month] as 'Month', 
    pmc2.pd_name_of_project as 'Name of Project',
    tbl_div.name AS 'Name of Advisory Services Division',
    TBL_PMC_UNIT.UNIT_NAME AS 'Name of Unit',
    pmc2.pd_project_type as 'Project Type',
    pmc2.accepted_tender_cost as 'Accepted Tender Cost',
    pmc2.work_order_date as 'Work Order Date',
    pmc2.tender_period_months as 'Tender Period',
    pmc2.project_completion_date as 'Project Completion Date',
    pmc2.per_pmc_charges as '% Of PMC Charges',
    pmc2.total_pmc_charges_scheme as 'Total PMC amount   of the Scheme',
    pmc2.bill_amount_certified_upto_previous_month as 'Bill amount certified upto previous Month',     
    pmc2.total_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Total PMC charges  upto previous Month',
    pmc2.receipt_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Receipt of PMC Charges upto previous Month',
    pmc2.balance_of_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Balance of PMC charges upto previous Month',
    pmc2.bill_amount_certified_current_month as 'Bill amount certified During Current Month',
    pmc2.PMC_charges_for_current_month as ' PMC charges  During Current Month',
    pmc2.receipt_PMC_charges_current_month as 'Receipt of PMC Charges During Current Monthh',
    pmc2.balance_of_PMC_charges_current_month as 'Balance of PMC charges During Current Month',
    pmc1.salary_allowance as 'Salary & Allowance Division'
FROM
(
    SELECT [month] as 'Month',
        SUM(pmc.salary_allowance) salary_allowance
    FROM TBL_PMC
    GROUP BY [month]
) pmc1 
INNER JOIN TBL_PMC pmc2
    ON pmc1.[month] = pmc2.[month]
INNER JOIN TBL_DIV 
    ON TBL_DIV.ID = pmc2.DIV_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_PMC_UNIT 
    ON TBL_PMC_UNIT.ID=pmc2.UNIT_ID  
WHERE pmc2.div_id= 17 
    --and pmc.unit_id=@unit_id;
```

This places your `SUM()` within a sub-query and then you will only `GROUP BY` a few fields in the sub-query, then to get the remaining fields you want from the `TBL_PMC` you `JOIN` the table again.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
select a.*,b.[Salary & Allowance Division] from 
(select  
    pmc.[month] as 'Month', 
    pmc.pd_name_of_project as 'Name of Project',
    tbl_div.name AS 'Name of Advisory Services Division',
    TBL_PMC_UNIT.UNIT_NAME AS 'Name of Unit',
    pmc.pd_project_type as 'Project Type',
    pmc.accepted_tender_cost as 'Accepted Tender Cost',
    pmc.work_order_date as 'Work Order Date',
    pmc.tender_period_months as 'Tender Period',
    pmc.project_completion_date as 'Project Completion Date',
    pmc.per_pmc_charges as '% Of PMC Charges',
    pmc.total_pmc_charges_scheme as 'Total PMC amount   of the Scheme',
    pmc.bill_amount_certified_upto_previous_month as 'Bill amount certified upto previous Month',     
    pmc.total_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Total PMC charges  upto previous Month',
    pmc.receipt_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Receipt of PMC Charges upto previous Month',
    pmc.balance_of_PMC_charges_upto_previous_month as 'Balance of PMC charges upto previous Month',
    pmc.bill_amount_certified_current_month as 'Bill amount certified During Current Month',
    pmc.PMC_charges_for_current_month as ' PMC charges  During Current Month',
    pmc.receipt_PMC_charges_current_month as 'Receipt of PMC Charges During Current Monthh',
    pmc.balance_of_PMC_charges_current_month as 'Balance of PMC charges During Current Month'
FROM 
    TBL_PMC pmc 
        INNER JOIN TBL_DIV 
            ON TBL_DIV.ID = pmc.DIV_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_PMC_UNIT 
            ON TBL_PMC_UNIT.ID=pmc.UNIT_ID  
WHERE 
    pmc.div_id= 17 
    --and pmc.unit_id=@unit_id;
group by  
    pmc.[month]
) a left join 

(select  
       pmc.[month] as 'Month', 
       SUM(pmc.salary_allowance) as 'Salary & Allowance Division'
FROM 
    TBL_PMC pmc 
        INNER JOIN TBL_DIV 
            ON TBL_DIV.ID = pmc.DIV_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_PMC_UNIT 
            ON TBL_PMC_UNIT.ID=pmc.UNIT_ID  
WHERE 
    pmc.div_id= 17 
    --and pmc.unit_id=@unit_id;
group by  
    pmc.[month]) b

on a.month = b.month
```